# Azure Synapse Serverless SQL Pools - how to optimize notebook

Tags: python, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, serverless-framework, azure-synapse

Is there a better way to optimize the following notebook?  Currently it takes 2 minutes and 20 seconds to run.  How can I improve performance?  Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Environment:

- medium sized spark pool (8 vCores/64 GB) with 3-30 nodes and 10 executors
- ADLSG2 premium (solid state drives)

Set the environment variables

```
    environment = "mydatalake"
    fileFormat = "parquet"
```

Function - set the path of where to load the source parquet files from

```
    tblName = ""
    fldrName = ""
    dbName = ""
    filePrefix = ""

    # Create the function
    def fn_PathSource(fldrName,dbName,tblName,fileFormat,filePrefix):
        str_path0 = "spark.read.load("
        str_path1 = "'abfss://"
        str_path2 = ".dfs.core.windows.net/sources"
        str_path3 = ", format="
        return f"{str_path0}{str_path1}{fldrName}@{environment}{str_path2}/{dbName}/{tblName}/{dbName}{filePrefix}{tblName}.{fileFormat}'{str_path3}'{fileFormat}')"
```

Function - set the path where the table data will be stored in the datalake

```
    # Create the variables used by the function
    tblName = ""
    fldrName = ""
    dbName = ""

    # Create the function
    def fn_Path(fldrName,dbName,tblName):
        str_path1 = "abfss://"
        str_path2 = ".dfs.core.windows.net"
        return f"{str_path1}{fldrName}@{environment}{str_path2}/{dbName}/{tblName}/"
```

Function - get the latest version of the records

```
    import hashlib
    from pyspark.sql.functions import md5, concat_ws,col

    # Create the variables used by the function
    uniqueId = ""
    versionId = ""
    tblName = ""

    # Create the function
    def fn_ReadLatestVrsn(uniqueId,versionId,tblName):
        df_Max = spark.sql(f"SELECT {uniqueId},MAX({versionId}) AS {versionId}Max FROM {tblName} GROUP BY {uniqueId}")
        df_Max.createOrReplaceTempView(f"{tblName}Max")

        df_Latest = spark.sql(f"SELECT {uniqueId},{versionId}Max FROM {tblName}Max")
        df_Latest = df_Latest.withColumn("HashKey",md5(concat_ws("",col(f"{uniqueId}").cast("string"),col(f"{versionId}Max").cast("string"))))
        df_Latest.createOrReplaceTempView(f"{tblName}Latest")

        df_Hash = spark.sql(f"SELECT * FROM {tblName} t1")
        df_Hash = df_Hash.withColumn("HashKey",md5(concat_ws("",col(f"{uniqueId}").cast("string"),col(f"{versionId}").cast("string"))))
        df_Hash.createOrReplaceTempView(f"{tblName}Hash")

        df_Final = spark.sql(f"SELECT DISTINCT t1.* FROM {tblName}Hash t1 INNER JOIN {tblName}Latest t2 ON t1.HashKey = t2.HashKey")
        df_Final.createOrReplaceTempView(f"{tblName}")
        return spark.sql(f"SELECT * FROM {tblName}")
```

Load data frames with source table data

```
        DF_tblBitSize = eval(fn_PathSource("silver","MineDB","tblBitSize","parquet","_dbo_"))
        DF_tblDailyReport = eval(fn_PathSource("silver","MineDB","tblDailyReport","parquet","_dbo_"))
        DF_tblDailyReportHole = eval(fn_PathSource("silver","MineDB","tblDailyReportHole","parquet","_dbo_"))
        DF_tblDailyReportHoleActivity = eval(fn_PathSource("silver","MineDB","tblDailyReportHoleActivity","parquet","_dbo_"))
        DF_tblDailyReportHoleActivityHours = eval(fn_PathSource("silver","MineDB","tblDailyReportHoleActivityHours","parquet","_dbo_"))
        DF_tblDailyReportShift = eval(fn_PathSource("silver","MineDB","tblDailyReportShift","parquet","_dbo_"))
        DF_tblDrill = eval(fn_PathSource("silver","MineDB","tblDrill","parquet","_dbo_"))
        DF_tblDrillType = eval(fn_PathSource("silver","MineDB","tblDrillType","parquet","_dbo_"))
        DF_tblEmployee = eval(fn_PathSource("silver","MineDB","tblEmployee","parquet","_dbo_"))
        DF_tblHole = eval(fn_PathSource("silver","MineDB","tblHole","parquet","_dbo_"))
        DF_tblMineProject = eval(fn_PathSource("silver","MineDB","tblMineProject","parquet","_dbo_"))
        DF_tblShift = eval(fn_PathSource("silver","MineDB","tblShift","parquet","_dbo_"))
        DF_tblUnit = eval(fn_PathSource("silver","MineDB","tblUnit","parquet","_dbo_"))
        DF_tblUnitType = eval(fn_PathSource("silver","MineDB","tblUnitType","parquet","_dbo_"))
        DF_tblWorkSubCategory = eval(fn_PathSource("silver","MineDB","tblWorkSubCategory","parquet","_dbo_"))
        DF_tblWorkSubCategoryType = eval(fn_PathSource("silver","MineDB","tblWorkSubCategoryType","parquet","_dbo_"))
        DF_v_Dashboards_CompanyContracts= eval(fn_PathSource("silver","MineDB","v_Dashboards_CompanyContracts","parquet","_"))
        DF_v_DailyReportShiftDrillers = eval(fn_PathSource("silver","MineDB","v_DailyReportShiftDrillers","parquet","_"))
        DF_v_ActivityCharges = eval(fn_PathSource("silver","MineDB","v_ActivityCharges","parquet","_"))
```

Convert dataframes to temporary views that can be used in SQL

```
        DF_tblBitSize.createOrReplaceTempView("tblBitSize")
        DF_tblDailyReport.createOrReplaceTempView("tblDailyReport")
        DF_tblDailyReportHole.createOrReplaceTempView("tblDailyReportHole")
        DF_tblDailyReportHoleActivity.createOrReplaceTempView("tblDailyReportHoleActivity")
        DF_tblDailyReportHoleActivityHours.createOrReplaceTempView("tblDailyReportHoleActivityHours")
        DF_tblDailyReportShift.createOrReplaceTempView("tblDailyReportShift")
        DF_tblDrill.createOrReplaceTempView("tblDrill")
        DF_tblDrillType.createOrReplaceTempView("tblDrillType")
        DF_tblEmployee.createOrReplaceTempView("tblEmployee")
        DF_tblHole.createOrReplaceTempView("tblHole")
        DF_tblMineProject.createOrReplaceTempView("tblMineProject")
        DF_tblShift.createOrReplaceTempView("tblShift")
        DF_tblUnit.createOrReplaceTempView("tblUnit")
        DF_tblUnitType.createOrReplaceTempView("tblUnitType")
        DF_tblWorkSubCategory.createOrReplaceTempView("tblWorkSubCategory")
        DF_tblWorkSubCategoryType.createOrReplaceTempView("tblWorkSubCategoryType")                                                 DF_v_Dashboards_CompanyContracts.createOrReplaceTempView("v_Dashboards_CompanyContracts")
        DF_v_DailyReportShiftDrillers.createOrReplaceTempView("v_DailyReportShiftDrillers")
        DF_v_ActivityCharges.createOrReplaceTempView("v_ActivityCharges")
```

Load latest data into views

When an existing record is updated (or a soft delete occurs) in the source system table, Azure Data Factory captures that change by creating an incremental parquet file. The same occurs when a new record is created. During the merge process, all of the incremental files are merged into one parquet file. For the existing record that was updated (or a soft deleted occured), the merge creates two versions of that record, appending the latest version. If you were to query the merged parquet file, you would see a duplicate record.
Therefore, to see only the latest version of that record, we need to remove the prior version. This function will ensure that we are looking at the most up to date version of all records.

** Special note: this logic is not necessary for tables with records that do not get soft deleted (e.g. tables without a LastModDateTime or ActiveInd column), therefore, we do not apply this function to those tables

```
    DF_tblBitSize = fn_ReadLatestVrsn("BitSizeID","LastModDateTime","tblBitSize")
    DF_tblDailyReport = fn_ReadLatestVrsn("DailyReportID","LastModDateTime","tblDailyReport")
    DF_tblDailyReportHole = fn_ReadLatestVrsn("DailyReportHoleID","LastModDateTime","tblDailyReportHole")
    DF_tblDailyReportHoleActivity = fn_ReadLatestVrsn("DailyReportHoleActivityID","LastModDateTime","tblDailyReportHoleActivity")
    DF_tblDailyReportHoleActivityHours = fn_ReadLatestVrsn("DailyReportHoleActivityHoursID","LastModDateTime","tblDailyReportHoleActivityHours")
    DF_tblDailyReportShift = fn_ReadLatestVrsn("DailyReportShiftID","LastModDateTime","tblDailyReportShift")
    DF_tblDrill = fn_ReadLatestVrsn("DrillID","LastModDateTime","tblDrill")
    DF_tblEmployee = fn_ReadLatestVrsn("EmployeeID","LastModDateTime","tblEmployee")
    DF_tblHole = fn_ReadLatestVrsn("HoleID","LastModDateTime","tblHole")
    DF_tblMineProject = fn_ReadLatestVrsn("MineProjectID","LastModDateTime","tblMineProject")
    DF_tblShift = fn_ReadLatestVrsn("ShiftID","LastModDateTime","tblShift")
    DF_tblWorkSubCategoryType = fn_ReadLatestVrsn("WorkSubCategoryTypeID","LastModDateTime","tblWorkSubCategoryType")
```

CTE_UnitConversion

```
    %%sql
    CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP VIEW  CTE_UnitConversion AS
    (
        SELECT 
            u.UnitID
            ,ut.UnitType
            ,u.UnitName
            ,u.UnitAbbr
            ,COALESCE(CAST(u.Conversion AS FLOAT),1) AS Conversion
        FROM 
            tblUnit u 
            INNER JOIN tblUnitType ut 
                ON u.UnitTypeID = ut.UnitTypeID
                AND ut.UnitType IN ('Distance','Depth')
        UNION
        SELECT 
            -1 AS UnitID
            ,'Unknown' AS UnitType
            ,'Unknown' AS UnitName
            ,'Unknown' AS UnitAbbr
            ,1 AS Conversion
    )
```

CTE_Dashboards_BaseData

```
    %%sql
    CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP VIEW  CTE_Dashboards_BaseData AS
    (
        SELECT 
            CC.ContractID,
            CC.ProjectID,
            CAST(DR.ReportDate AS DATE) AS ReportDate,
            D.DrillID,
            CAST(D.DrillName AS STRING) AS DrillName,
            DT.DrillTypeID,
            CAST(DT.DrillType AS STRING) AS DrillType,
            CAST(NULL AS STRING) AS HoleName,
            CAST(S.ShiftName AS STRING) AS ShiftName,
            STRING(CONCAT(E.LastName,' ',E.FirstName)) AS Supervisor,
            CAST(DRSD.Drillers AS STRING) AS Driller,
            CAST(NULL AS FLOAT) AS TotalMeterage,
            CAST(NULL AS FLOAT) AS Depth,
            CAST(NULL AS STRING) AS DepthUnit,
            CAST(NULL AS FLOAT) AS ManHours,
            CAST(NULL AS FLOAT) AS Payrollhours,
            CAST(NULL AS FLOAT) AS ActivityHours,
            CAST(NULL AS FLOAT) AS EquipmentHours,
            CAST(NULL AS FLOAT) AS Quantity,
            CAST(NULL AS STRING) AS Category,
            CAST(NULL AS STRING) AS SubCategory,
            CAST(NULL AS STRING) AS HoursType,
            CAST(NULL AS STRING) AS BitSize,
            CAST(DRS.DailyReportShiftID AS BIGINT) AS DailyReportShiftID,
            CAST(DRS.ShiftID AS INT) AS ShiftID,
            CAST(NULL AS TIMESTAMP) AS CompleteDateTime,
            CAST(NULL AS STRING) AS HoleCompletionStatus,
            CAST(NULL AS STRING) AS Notes,
            CAST(NULL AS INT) AS HoleID,
            CAST(NULL AS FLOAT) AS DistanceFrom,
            CAST(NULL AS FLOAT) AS DistanceTo,
            CAST(NULL AS STRING) AS DistanceFromToUnit,
            CAST(NULL AS FLOAT) AS Distance,
            CAST(NULL AS STRING) AS DistanceUnit,
            CAST(NULL AS STRING) AS FluidUnit,
            CAST(NULL AS FLOAT) AS FluidVolume,
            CAST(NULL AS STRING) AS UID,
            CAST(NULL AS FLOAT) AS MaxDepth,
            CAST(NULL AS FLOAT) AS Penetration,
            CAST(NULL AS FLOAT) AS Charges,
            CAST(DR.Status AS STRING) AS Status,
            CAST(DRS.LastModDateTime AS TIMESTAMP) AS LastModDateTime
        FROM 
            v_Dashboards_CompanyContracts CC
            LEFT JOIN tblDailyReport DR ON CC.ContractID = DR.ContractID AND CC.ProjectID = DR.ProjectID
            LEFT JOIN tblDailyReportShift DRS ON DR.DailyReportID = DRS.DailyReportID
            LEFT JOIN tblShift S ON DRS.ShiftID = S.ShiftID
            LEFT JOIN tblDrill D ON DR.DrillID = D.DrillID
            LEFT JOIN tblDrillType DT ON D.DrillTypeID = DT.DrillTypeID
            LEFT JOIN tblEmployee E ON DRS.SupervisorID = E.EmployeeID
            LEFT JOIN v_DailyReportShiftDrillers DRSD ON DRS.DailyReportShiftID = DRSD.DailyReportShiftID
        WHERE 
            DR.Status <> 'Deleted'
    )
```

CTE_DailyReportHoleActivityManHours

```
    %%sql
    CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP VIEW  CTE_DailyReportHoleActivityManHours AS
    (
      SELECT 
        DailyReportHoleActivityID
        ,SUM(HoursAsFloat) AS ManHours
      FROM 
        tblDailyReportHoleActivityHours
      WHERE 
        ActiveInd = 'Y'
      GROUP BY 
        DailyReportHoleActivityID
    )
```

Activity charges

```
    %%sql
    CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP VIEW SECTION_1 AS
    (
        SELECT 
            BD.ContractID
            ,BD.ProjectID
            ,CAST(ReportDate AS DATE) AS ReportDate
            ,DrillID
            ,DRHA.Depth
            ,DPU.UnitAbbr AS DepthUnit
            ,DPU.UnitID AS DepthUnitID
            ,DRHAMH.ManHours
            ,DRHA.ActivityHoursAsFloat AS ActivityHours
            ,WSC.WorkSubCategoryName AS Category
            ,WSCT.TypeName AS SubCategory
            ,CASE 
                WHEN (COALESCE(AC.Charges,0) = 0 AND COALESCE(AC.BillableCount, 0) = 0) OR DRHA.Billable='N' THEN 'Non-Billable'
                WHEN AC.DefinedRateName IS NOT NULL AND DRHA.Billable <> 'N' THEN AC.DefinedRateName
                ELSE WSC.WorkSubCategoryName 
            END AS HoursType
            ,BS.BitSizeID AS BitSizeID
            ,BS.BitSize
            ,DRHA.BitID AS BitID
            ,BD.DailyReportShiftID
            ,DRHA.Notes
            ,H.HoleID
            ,DRHA.DistanceFrom
            ,DRHA.DistanceTo
            ,DFU.UnitAbbr AS DistanceFromToUnit
            ,DFU.UnitID AS DistanceFromToUnitID
            ,DRHA.Distance
            ,DU.UnitID AS DistanceUnitID
            ,CASE 
                WHEN WSC.WorkCategoryId  = 1 THEN MAX(COALESCE(DRHA.DistanceTo, 0)) OVER ( PARTITION BY H.HoleID, WSC.WorkSubCategoryName  ORDER BY H.HoleID, ReportDate, BD.ShiftID, DRHA.SequenceNumber, DRHA.CreateDateTime, DRHA.DistanceTo)
                ELSE NULL
            END AS MaxDepth
            ,CASE 
                WHEN WSC.WorkCategoryId  = 1 THEN DRHA.Penetration
                ELSE 0
            END AS Penetration
            ,COALESCE(AC.Charges,0) AS Charges
            ,BD.Status
            ,H.MineProjectID
            ,CAST(DRHA.LastModDateTime AS TIMESTAMP) AS LastModDateTime
        FROM 
            CTE_Dashboards_BaseData BD
            INNER JOIN tblDailyReportHole DRH ON BD.DailyReportShiftID = DRH.DailyReportShiftID
            INNER JOIN tblDailyReportHoleActivity DRHA ON DRH.DailyReportHoleID = DRHA.DailyReportHoleID
            INNER JOIN tblWorkSubCategory WSC ON DRHA.WorkSubCategoryID = WSC.WorkSubCategoryID
            LEFT JOIN tblHole H ON DRH.HoleID = H.HoleID
            LEFT JOIN tblBitSize BS ON DRHA.BitSizeID = BS.BitSizeID
            LEFT JOIN tblUnit DPU ON DRHA.DepthUnitID = DPU.UnitID 
            LEFT JOIN tblUnit DFU ON DRHA.DistanceFromToUnitID = DFU.UnitID 
            LEFT JOIN tblUnit DU ON DRHA.DistanceUnitID = DU.UnitID 
            LEFT JOIN tblWorkSubCategoryType WSCT ON DRHA.TypeID = WSCT.WorkSubCategoryTypeID
            LEFT JOIN v_ActivityCharges AC ON DRHA.DailyReportHoleActivityID = AC.DailyReportHoleActivityID
            LEFT JOIN CTE_DailyReportHoleActivityManHours DRHAMH ON DRHA.DailyReportHoleActivityID = DRHAMH.DailyReportHoleActivityID
        WHERE 
            DRH.ActiveInd = 'Y' 
            AND DRHA.ActiveInd = 'Y'
    )
```

Create FACT_Activity table

```
    df = spark.sql("""
        SELECT
            ReportDate
            ,DrillingCompanyID
            ,MiningCompanyID
            ,DrillID
            ,ProjectID
            ,ContractID
            ,LocationID
            ,HoleID
            ,DailyReportShiftId
            ,MineProjectID
            ,BitID
            ,TRIM(UPPER(BitSize)) AS BitSize
            ,-1 AS TimesheetId
            ,CurrencyID
            ,TRIM(UPPER(Category)) AS Category
            ,TRIM(UPPER(SubCategory)) AS SubCategory
            ,TRIM(UPPER(HoursType)) AS HoursType
            ,TRIM(UPPER(Notes)) AS Notes
            ,ApprovalStatus
            ,Depth AS Depth
            ,(Depth/COALESCE(Depth.Conversion,1)) AS DepthMeters
            ,Manhours
            ,ActivityHours
            ,DistanceFrom
            ,DistanceTo
            ,Distance
            ,Penetration
            ,(DistanceFrom/Distance.Conversion) AS DistanceFromMeters
            ,(DistanceTo/Distance.Conversion) AS DistanceToMeters
            ,(Distance/Distance.Conversion) AS DistanceMeters
            ,(Penetration/Distance.Conversion) AS PenetrationMeters
            ,DepthUnitID
            ,DistanceFromToUnitID
            ,Charges
            ,LastModDateTime
            ,ReportApprovalRequired
        FROM
        (
            SELECT 
                COALESCE(CAST(ReportDate AS DATE),'01/01/1900') AS ReportDate
                ,COALESCE(DrillingCompanyID,-1) AS DrillingCompanyID
                ,COALESCE(MiningCompanyID,-1) AS MiningCompanyID
                ,COALESCE(DrillID,-1) AS DrillID
                ,COALESCE(C.ProjectID, -1) AS ProjectID
                ,COALESCE(C.ContractID,-1) AS ContractID
                ,COALESCE(C.LocationID,-1) AS LocationID
                ,COALESCE(HoleID,-1) AS HoleID
                ,COALESCE(DailyReportShiftID,-1) AS DailyReportShiftId
                ,COALESCE(MP.MineProjectID,-1) AS MineProjectID
                ,COALESCE(BitID,-1) AS BitID
                ,COALESCE(BitSize,'UNKNOWN') AS BitSize
                ,COALESCE(DepthUnitID,-1) AS DepthUnitID
                ,COALESCE(DistanceFromToUnitID,-1) AS DistanceFromToUnitID
                ,COALESCE(DistanceUnitID,-1) AS DistanceUnitID
                ,COALESCE(C.CurrencyID,-1) AS CurrencyID
                ,COALESCE(Category,'Unknown') AS Category
                ,COALESCE(SubCategory,'UNKNOWN') AS SubCategory
                ,COALESCE(HoursType,'UNKNOWN') AS HoursType
                ,SUBSTRING(Notes,0,250) AS Notes
                ,COALESCE(U.Status,'Unknown') AS ApprovalStatus
                ,COALESCE(Depth,0) AS Depth
                ,COALESCE(Manhours,0) AS Manhours
                ,COALESCE(ActivityHours,0) AS ActivityHours
                ,COALESCE(DistanceFrom,0) AS DistanceFrom
                ,COALESCE(DistanceTo,0) AS DistanceTo
                ,COALESCE(Distance,0) AS Distance
                ,COALESCE(Penetration,0) AS Penetration
                ,COALESCE(Charges,0) AS Charges
                ,COALESCE(CAST(U.LastModDateTime AS TIMESTAMP),'1900/01/01 00:00:00') AS LastModDateTime
                ,C.ReportApprovalRequired
            FROM
                SECTION_1 U
                LEFT JOIN v_Dashboards_CompanyContracts C ON U.ContractID = C.ContractID AND COALESCE(U.ProjectID,-1) = C.ProjectID
                LEFT JOIN tblMineProject MP ON U.MineProjectID = MP.MineProjectID AND MP.ActiveInd = 'Y'
        ) TBL1
        INNER JOIN CTE_UnitConversion Distance ON tbl1.DistanceFromToUnitID = Distance.UnitID
        INNER JOIN CTE_UnitConversion Depth ON tbl1.DepthUnitID = Depth.UnitID
    """)
```

Create the table and write to the datalake

```
    tblName = "fact_activity"
    fldrName = "myfolder"
    dbName = "mydatabase"

    path = fn_Path(fldrName,dbName,tblName)
    path

    # Reduce the number of parquet files written using coalesce and write the dataframe to the datalake
    df.coalesce(1).write.format("parquet").mode("overwrite").save(path)

    # Drop the table (only dropping the metadata) if it exists in the lakehouse database
    spark.sql(f"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {dbName}.{tblName}")

    # Now create the table (metadata only) and point it at the data in the datalake
    spark.sql(f"CREATE TABLE {dbName}.{tblName} USING PARQUET LOCATION '{path}'")
```

Release SQL views from memory

```
    %%sql
    DROP VIEW SECTION_1;
    DROP VIEW CTE_DailyReportHoleActivityManHours;
    DROP VIEW CTE_Dashboards_BaseData;
    DROP VIEW CTE_UnitConversion;
    DROP VIEW tblBitSize;
    DROP VIEW tblDailyReport;
    DROP VIEW tblDailyReportHole;
    DROP VIEW tblDailyReportHoleActivity;
    DROP VIEW tblDailyReportHoleActivityHours;
    DROP VIEW tblDailyReportShift;
    DROP VIEW tblDrill;
    DROP VIEW tblEmployee;
    DROP VIEW tblHole;
    DROP VIEW tblMineProject;
    DROP VIEW tblShift;
```

Release data frames from memory

```
    del DF_tblBitSize
    del DF_tblDailyReport
    del DF_tblDailyReportHole
    del DF_tblDailyReportHoleActivity
    del DF_tblDailyReportHoleActivityHours
    del DF_tblDailyReportShift
    del DF_tblDrill
    del DF_tblDrillType
    del DF_tblEmployee
    del DF_tblHole
    del DF_tblMineProject
    del DF_tblShift
    del DF_tblUnit
    del DF_tblUnitType
    del DF_tblWorkSubCategory
    del DF_v_Dashboards_CompanyContracts
    del DF_v_DailyReportShiftDrillers
    del DF_v_ActivityCharges
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from **Release SQL views from memory** and **Release data frames from memory** everything looks fine.

If your application required to query the data frequently and there is requirement to create `VIEWS`, you can create the EXTERNAL TABLE in Dedicated SQL Pool and save the VIEWS for the tables using Synapse SQL. This would be more efficient and there won't be need to drop VIEWS and release dataframes every time you need the data.

You can also [create and use native external tables using SQL pools in Azure Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/create-use-external-tables) as Native external tables have better performance when compared to external tables with `TYPE=HADOOP` in their external data source definition. This is because native external tables use native code to access external data.

You can also refer [Best practices for serverless SQL pool in Azure Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/best-practices-serverless-sql-pool) to get more details regarding performance optimization.

Comment: Thank you @UtkarshPal-MT for your suggestions.  I'll give it a try and let you know if it helps with performance.

Comment: Sure, Phil. Update me in case further info required or any other issue.